# Evaluate binary operations in both PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, evaluation

We have a web application which lets users customize behaviour by writing in a small scripting language. One problem we've stumbled upon is that some operations are evaluated differently in PHP and JavaScript. Example:

```
-1 < 'A'
```

This code is true in PHP but false in JavaScript.

Did anyone else ever face this problem, and what approach could be sensible to take?

**Edit**: Correction, it's true in PHP but false in JavaScript.

Comment: one option would be to send front-end expressions to the server and evaluate there (usual caveats apply).

Comment: @georg Yes, we've thought about that.

Comment: What *should* this evaluate to?!

Comment: Does explicitly casting the values to numbers/string help?

Comment: Types are evaluated differently between the 2 languages. It may help to look at: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ for javascript and http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for php.

As @georg mentioned earlier you're probably better off running your evaluations server side. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP number and string considered as different every string compared with number is zero.

But Javascript that considered those values in alphabetical order here `a<b` similar `c>b`  in this way numbers are less than alphabets

Comment: But that does not explain why `'-1' < 'A'` is true in JavaScript, but `-1 < 'A'` is false?

Comment: here PHP consider `-1 `as number Javascript Consider `- `as special character as alphabetical order when comparing it to a string

Comment: So in `-1 < 'A'`, is JavaScript actually casting `-1` to a character?